# I want to get output result from second table based on first table rows output in json-php

Tags: php, json

I have knowledge of PHP but I am still learning Json. First of all I want to clear what I am looking for. I have two tables in mysql database, table1(**users**) and table2(**business**). Table "users" contains these rows(id, uid, business_name) and table "business" contains these rows(id, uid, category).

I have following code in PHP page:

```
if(isset($_GET['catName'])) {

    $cat = $_GET['catName'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, uid, category FROM business WHERE category = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(array($_GET['catName']));
    $arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

I am able to get json output on my html page e.g.
101, 102, 103 and so on.

But I want to get business_name rows like ABC Business, XYZ Business, 123 Business and so on from second table "business" based on the output uid from first table. In brief, I want business_name output instead of uid output from second table.
Please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `JOIN`the business table and read the `bussiness_name` column.

Comment: What has this to do with json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Chris and Jormundir. Joining the both tables really solved my problem. This is what I have done:

> $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT business.uid, users.business_name FROM business,users WHERE business.uid = users.uid AND business.category= ? ");

In html page I have put "business_name" array instead of "uid" and I have got result whatever I was looking for.

Thanks you so much all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an associative array, with the results from the query. It sounds like you want the business names, but you are not querying for them.

So the first step would be fix your broken query!

It's difficult to tell what you want from the query, but you're mixing the users table with the business table, so I'm guessing you really want business names based on users.

```
SELECT b.business_name FROM users u JOIN business b ON u.uid = b.uid WHERE category = ?
```

Then, you have to access your $arr variable correctly to get the business names

```
foreach ($arr as $bus_sql_result) {
    echo $bus_sql_result['business_name']."\n";
}
```

This is not in JSON format, I'm not sure what JSON has to do with what you want, but if you really want it that way, you could try something like

```
$business_names = array();
foreach ($arr as $bus_sql_result) {
    $business_names[] = $bus_sql_result['business_name'];
}
echo json_encode($business_names);
```